# use elements from list to create a spinner in Android

Tags: android, xml, arraylist

I am new to android and I have a arrayList named cityNames in my MianActivity.java file.
I want to put the contents of the arrayList into the spinner without copying the contents in the strings.xml file. How can I do that?

The code is given below. But there is no spinner created when I am running the project on emulator.

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        String[] cityNames = {"Jaipur","Bangalore","KOta","Hyderabad"};
        spinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    cityNames ));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

> .XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like so (assuming `Spinner` is decalred inside `Activity`, otherwise you should pass correct context instead of `this`):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cityNames));
```

Comment: Lets assume I declare a spinner(named spinner1) in activity_main.xml and now I want to put the elements in that spinner. What do I have to change in the code given above?

Comment: can you please review my code as I edited the problem after the answer given by you.

Comment: @user3235169 you should add the spinner to your `activity_main.xml` and then just use the code I've provided (with `findViewById`)